# Is hadoop3.1.1 not supported?

Tags: hadoop, alluxio

When I build alluxio with following cmd.

```
    mvn -T 4C clean install -pl underfs/hdfs/ \
   -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DskipTests -Dlicense.skip=true \
   -Dcheckstyle.skip=true -Dfindbugs.skip=true \
   -Pufs-hadoop-3 -Dufs.hadoop.version=3.1.1
```

It raises an error `Failed to execute goal on project alluxio-underfs-hdfs: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.alluxio:alluxio-underfs-hdfs:jar:2.7.4: Could not find artifact org.alluxio:alluxio-shaded-hadoop:jar:3.1.1 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)`

Does it mean hadoop3.1.1 is not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to build specific Hadoop UFS to enable hadoop 3.1.1 in addition to what is pre-built: https://docs.alluxio.io/os/user/stable/en/contributor/Building-Alluxio-From-Source.html#build-different-hdfs-under-storage.

If you are on a specific tag for Alluxio like v2.8.0, try building it on master branch or a branch like `branch-2.8`. If all else doesn't work, you might have to build the entire project, try to remove the `-pl underfs/hdfs/`.